# Limit the change password attempts in spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-cognito

I want to Limit the change password attempts in spring boot app, I am using aws cognito for  access control.

I am newbie for spring boot app, so need some suggestions on this, I want to make it 3 times per day restrictions.

Any help or suggestion is most welcome

Answer (score 0):

It is not configurable as per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html#limits-soft). They have protection mechanisms to prevent users from abusing forgot password APIs
[image]

Comment: thanks for quick reply, if not possible through aws cognito, is there any chance we can achieve it at app level